# Notification sending to single user and to admin role users using Signalr in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

basicly i did a hub which sends notification when some action happens in repository . I want to change this to signle User sending , for example to send notificaiton if action happened on that user or to send all notifications to the admin role users.

right now i have just a hub  and i use

```
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("displayNotification", "");
```

and in html side

```
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/NotificationHub")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

    connection.on('displayNotification', () => {
        getNotification()
        toastr.info("You hava a new Notification");
    }
    );

    async function start() {
        try {
            await connection.start();
            console.log("connected");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
        }
    };

    connection.onclose(async () => {
        await start();
    });

    start();
```

Comment: You need to know to whom the notification should be sent, more precisely know the connection id of the target user. Assuming that you have one server with a hub, you can create an in-memory store (dictionary e.g.) associating the connection id with the user. Add entry on user connected, remove when disconnected. Then, when some action happens in your repository, retrieve information to which user it is related, use that info as a key to retrieve that user connection id from the in-memory store. Finally, send the notification if the connection id is found (user is connected).

Comment: Hi @lukacecxladze, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to change this to signle User sending , for example to send notificaiton if action happened on that user or to send all notifications to the admin role users.

When we call hub methods from outside of the Hub class, there's no `caller` associated with the invocation. Therefore, we can not use code snippet such as `Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message)` to send a message back to the caller.

To achieve your requirement of sending message to a specific/signle user, you can create single-user group (a group for signle user), then send a message to that group when you want to reach only that specific user.

And you can also add all admin users in a group, so that you can push notifications to all admin users by sending message to that group.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName_Here).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{message_here}");
```

For more information about "Groups in SignalR", please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0#groups-in-signalr

Besides, to achieve same requirement, as @Prolog mentioned, you can also map users to ConnectionId(s), then send messages to specific connected clients with following code snippet.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Clients(connectionIds_here).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{message_here}");
```